# Solving mixed system of equalities and inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, numerical-optimization

I have a mixed system of equalities and inequalities, for example:

$x + 2y +3z = 10\\
2x + 4y + 10z = 20\\
4x + y + z < 10$

where unknown variables $x, y, z$ are all real-valued.

How can get a solution (or the range of all feasible solutions) for this system? I understand this problem can be converted into a linear constrained optimisation problem, but I do not understand how.

Please help

Comment: You can solve the indeterminate system formed by the equations and plug the solution in the inequations. E.g. $z=0,x=10-2y\to-7y<-30$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the first equation with $2$, the eq.1 and eq. 2 read:

$2x + 4y +6z = 20\\
2x + 4y + 10z = 20\\$

Subtraction gives: $4z=0$ hence $z=0.$

From the first eq. we now derive $x=10-2y.$ Thus the Third eq. becomes: $4(10-2y)+y<1=$ or $y > \frac{30}{7}.$

Consequence: the set of solutions is given by:

$$ \{(10-2y, y,0): y > \frac{30}{7}\}.$$

Comment: I see, thank you. My problem is my system is usually composed of M equations and N inequalities (and M+N variables) where both M and N can be very large, making an analytical solution potentially tedious (in my limited knowledge)